# Use of ajax.googleapis.com is not China friendly

Tags: support, bug, google, china

I often use Stack Overflow from China, where Google based services are regularly blocked or severely hampered.

I have noticed that as of late, I am getting a lot of the following error:

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load.

Thereby rendering Stack Overflow useless.

Looking at the Chrome console, I notice that the reason is as follows:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Is is possible for Stack Overflow to host jQuery itself, therefore bypassing the [Great Firewall of China](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall_of_China)?

If not, what is the reason for this?

Comment: [This answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215868/why-does-stack-exchange-access-googleapis-com/215870#215870) provides some insight as to why the Google CDN is used.

Comment: There's also [this question and answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133786/add-a-fallback-for-jquery-in-case-it-fails-to-load-from-googles-cdn), which gives the (poor IMO) excuse as to why there is no fallback if `ajax.googleapis.com` is unavailable.

Comment: @Matt. I agree it is a very poor excuse - a Fallback can also be to another CDN . But anyhow see a solution here :  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270856/1244126

Comment: Maybe this will be of help: https://decentraleyes.org/

Comment: What about people who are concerned about privacy? I'm using FF56+NoScript to filter remote code from scorecardresearch.com and other third parties from SO. When browsing, it should be **my** choice whose remote code may run on **my** computer. Whether SO even works and how it works totally depends on Google. This must be a political choice, I can't believe it's lazyness. Seriously, how hard can it be to host jQuery locally, just like all other resources on SO?

Comment: @asmaier, I like the idea of decentraleyes.org, but it needs permission to: access your data for all websites, read and modify privacy settings, store unlimited amount of client-side data, access browser tabs and access browsers activity during navigation. And who do I trust all that? whois decentraleyes.org tells me that would be WHOISGUARD, INC. in Panama. Think twice.

Comment: @Code4R7 The registrar of the website decentraleyes.org has nothing to do with the offered plugin. The plugin is opensource and can be found on https://github.com/Synzvato/decentraleyes . So the person behind this is even known by real name, see https://github.com/Synzvato . You should also read the privacy policy "Decentraleyes does not collect any data of any kind.", see https://github.com/Synzvato/decentraleyes/wiki/Privacy-Policy . Please think thrice.

Comment: @asmaier Your links should have been on that site. The privacy policy is the best I've ever seen. The tool is a great concept. I'm ready to give it a try.

Comment: Good question...I still wonder why developers can't make request route to another CDN as backup if there is no response from Google CDN. This will open gateway to millions of Chinese developers. The collaboration will be awesome.

Comment: While there might be issues in China I want to point out that there are serious privacy concerns in using google services in general. I personally keep google services blocked as much as ever possible and appreciate pretty much that at least there's a 'use an alternate source' link!

Answer (score 21):

Technically, there are several possible ways to solve the CDN problem.

1. Replace the CDN hosted on google by another CDN that's not linked to Google. This includes for example, [MAXCDN](https://www.maxcdn.com/) used by https://code.jquery.com/ itself.  (There is also a feature request about this [Replace ajax.googleapis.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276458/replace-ajax-googleapis-com)). These alternatives and China probably do not have quarrels with each other and they are not likely to get blocked.
2. Use an alternative CDN such as [MAXCDN](https://www.maxcdn.com/) as a backup CDN. When the google-hosted CDN fail, fall back to the backup CDN. A popular SO question [Best way to use Google's hosted jQuery, but fall back to my hosted library on Google fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go), and the answers therein (among others) show how that can be done in JavaScript and HTML5.
3. hosting jQuery locally. Although reliable, this is not preferable performance-wise as pointed out in other answers provided or linked here.
4. If the SO idea is popular enough, probably a website similar to SO will be developed within the firewall.

Of course, whether this works depends on other factors.

1. some of identity/credential providers are blocked: Google, Facebook, (and OpenID in the past). So the users in China may only be able to register a native SO account.
2. the demand for using SO from China. A meta question here [What's up with China?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302667/whats-up-with-china) seems to suggest that there is a surge recently.
3. the resources and manpower available in SO to resolve this particular problem.

Comment: Your (4.) makes no sense. Users without access to http://ajax.googleapis.com will not be able to upvote anything nor leave a comment. So users which are actually affected by this problem will remain unheard on this platform unless they know how to work around this problem (I'd assume that's the minority).

Comment: [A website](https://segmentfault.com) similar to SO has already been developed. It plagiarized almost everything - including (almost) all badges (no bounty there, though).

Comment: 4. How more popular could SO get than it already is? Given the symbiotic relationship between SO and Google (the former providing a lot of search traffic in easily digestable format, the latter crawling SO ten times a second and being relied on as the primary search method for the whole of SO), I believe there must be deal saying SO is not functional without resoursces loaded from Google. Technically and gicen the typical user profile the benefit from cached jQuery from Google is negligible on both sides.

Comment: Actually, number 3 isn't just possible, [there's a plugin for the three major browsers](https://decentraleyes.org/) (Firefox, Chrome, and Opera) that does exactly that. I use it to speed up page load speeds (and it does a great job at that), but because it loads it locally, it bypasses the Google CDNs and would enable full functionality where Google for some reason is blocked. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320267/332043) also mentions a plugin called resource override that could help (although it appears to be manual). The point being, there are ways to solve it without SE.

Comment: "If the SO idea is popular enough, probably a website similar to SO will be developed within the firewal" If China continues to block SO indirectly via googleapis, that would actually make sense. They could also use the content from here (and even give attribution, making a link to a blocked site) and start from there. I wonder if something like this maybe already happened and outside of China simply nobody knows of it.

Comment: In 2020, this is a non-answer. SO already has a CDN for static files (sstatic.net) and it can be cached indefinitely using cache-busting methods. It would remove an entire DNS query and TLS connection. Besides the overhead with creating a TLS connection, the DNS record for ajax.google.com has a 60 second TTL. With HTTP/2, and a already needed connection to sstatic.net this file could be multiplexed loaded with the other JS files without needing another TCP connection and DNS query. The file should be moved for performances reasons alone.

Comment: About the credential providers: From a *privacy* point of view best you can do is having a native account anyway ;)

Answer (score 16):

As one of our developers [explains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215868/why-does-stack-exchange-access-googleapis-com/215870#215870):

> For technical reasons, we use the [Google CDN](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) for the jQuery files (a CDN is a Content Delivery Network - a bit of technology that makes distributing things like images and JavaScript libraries across the world faster) - that's what is hosted on ajax.googleapis.com. This is something many many sites do and as result many people will already have this library on their computer.

It turns out that [it's almost impossible to Sign Up at SE at China](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360/its-almost-impossible-to-sign-up-at-se-at-china/361#361) because [another script](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/openid.en.js) is also blocked. China even [blocks (intermittently) parts of our login system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287070/1438) that we host ourselves. As a result, most users in China will be better off using a VPN.

As China (and [other countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship#Network_tools) inclined to block portions of the internet), [plugs other holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Brinker,_or_The_Silver_Skates#Popular_culture:_the_legend_of_the_boy_and_the_dike), other [external dependencies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208) would need to be self-hosted as well. This doesn't seem like a good use of resources.

Comment: I'm not going to make flames. But I think, don't make google like a lady standing still there and let visitors to approach her. Maybe we took it for granted, we depend much more than necessary on google. Why stackoverflow.com not called stackoverflow.google.com? why must a script should host on google? where is the freedom of network turned so centerized? In fact, is it *good* to use Google CDN outside google?

Comment: @neoedmund It's good to use it because of the much higher likelihood of a user having it cached, thereby reducing their page load times.

Comment: [hola.org](https://hola.org/) seems to be blocked in China. As a result, most users in China just facing this problem now will be no better off after reading this "answer".

Comment: @neoedmund I fully agree with you. This makes us *yet* more dependent on Google and their server farms, which have conquered the whole world already anyway. And it goes on...It's just a few (hundred?) lines of JS code, nothing too spectacular. So even with 100k users per minute, this sort of "load" should be digestible on SO locally with no problems. It's just a matter of stubbornness IMHO.

Comment: @NickCraver Is there any recent evolution regarding China (and/or Stack Exchange jQuery file service)? https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com shows that the last 2 weeks, china visitors have gone from 50-80K to... 790K two day ago!?

Comment: @NickCraver a "feature" which _may_ possibly reduce page load times for _some_ users, which also with 100% certainty disables the site for other users... this is a very questionable decision. I've never worked at a company with a commercial product where that was an acceptable trade-off. (Especially given that it's very likely there are other options available to achieve the same benefit.)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. As If Google CDN is the only CDN on the planet. Microsoft CDN is not blocked and works fine for JQuery at least.

Comment: @SebastianGodelet And what happens when Microsoft's CDN gets blocked, and then MAXCDN, and then every other CDN on the planet? The problem is with the Chinese government, not Stack Overflow or their CDNs.

Comment: Of course the problem is on the government side, but the fix for this is in SEs hand. For now, it is just an artificial restriction due to a simple implementation detail. Note that Microsoft so far complies with the gov', s.th. they can operate in within China, Google chose to not comply, hence the blocking.

Comment: Finally I've understood the actual motive why they feel like having to *fetch* jQuery directly from Google CDN instead of simply hosting it locally: [big article here](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) I've almost been of the (rather stubborn) opinion: *Host it on your own servers, for if the remote server strikes, everything will be blocked and your visitors can no longer use your pages."*

Comment: @IanKemp Or you can say if the chinese government block Stack Overflow in the future, so we talk about googleapis wasting every one's time for now.  Even if the earth goes down, we do not need a stack overflow website too. Thats make no sense. What we talking is  why use google CDNs, there are so many choices.

Comment: Google sets a max-age of 365 days with a 30 day stale-while-revalidate cache on jQuery. Stack Exchange could easily do the same. The performance difference between hosting this on Google's CDN vs. internally on SE is minimal and would only be realized by users who either clear their cache daily or never visit the site. For users who clear their cache often, they would welcome this change as it is one less signal to google. I personally use Decentraleyes to block google CDN. It would also help Chinese users, and be one less DNS query & server that can have outages.

Comment: I believe it is business, not technical decision - SO gets crawled by Google ten times a second and SO relies on Google for searching rather than improving internal search (both stated by Joel Spolsky somewhere). I believe Google wouldn't be as friendly if SO weren't functionally relying on them. Technically, for SO themselves and for the typical user visiting many times a month/week/day, the benefot of hosting at Google CDN is negligible.

Comment: @NickCraver and Jon Ericson, please revisit [Jeff Atwood rejection to fallback to a secondary source when the primary one is blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10118/263422). It's been 10 years! Google is still blocked in China. And [there are technical solutions for that issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014251/1033581) that would help hundreds of millions of visitors.

Comment: "This doesn't seem like a good use of resources." Is this still the estimation in 2019, especially from a management point of view? More customers in China sound like it could be a good thing compared to the relatively low effort required here.

Comment: Low effort, and massive load on SE's CDN. No-one will have the file cached. That means 9.3M downloads of that file for the first day, on SO itself. Switching to SE's CDN completely removes the benefit of users probably having the file cached already.

Comment: @Cerbrus But that would only be a one time effect. Maybe SE could change the CDN only for visitors from China as some kind of compromise. There are millions of programmers in China and probably many of them speak English by now. I wonder if the estimation by the company changed in the last five years. This answer could be outdated.

Comment: Making assumptions about a user's location sounds like a very ugly hack... Switching CDNs would guarantee ___every___ visitor to the site, now and for the remainder of time, would have to download that file. Then SE might as well not use a CDN.

Comment: @Trilarion: I'm no expert, but it seems to me that we'd need to do a lot more than change a few configuration files to start doing business in China. ;-) Case study: [Google in China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_by_Google#China).

Comment: @JonEricson I don't really understand why China would like to block StackOverflow. It contains zero politics but lots of programming knowledge. There is some chance this is just a collateral damage. Anyway, I had the idea of making a static site with selected content from StackOverflow for a long time. If I ever come around doing it, I can pay attention to not using CDNs and if then additionally there are significant amounts of Chinese visitors, I can report back.

Comment: In 2019, this is a non-answer. SO uses Fastly CDN and we're talking about a static JS file that can be cached indefinitely using cache-busting methods. Not only would it have a minuscule impact on the backend servers due to Fastly caching, but it would remove an entire DNS query and TLS connection. Besides the overhead with creating a TLS connection, the DNS record for ajax.google.com has a 60 second TTL. With HTTP/2, this file could be multiplexed loaded with the other JS files being loaded without needing another TCP connection. The file should be moved for performances reasons alone.

Comment: You say it is faster to use Google's jQuery because it is probably in cache already.  But it represents a fraction of a second at most, and applies only the first time you visit StackOverflow.  How many times does it happen?

Comment: @FlorianF: I no longer work at Stack Overflow. I can say that making the site load quickly has always been a priority at the company and every little bit matter. I'm currently a community manager for another site and one of the top concerns we have is that our site has gotten slow to load because of a thousand (almost literally) decisions to take an extra fraction of a second here and there. I tend to think this particular exception is one worth making, but that is how you start down a slippery slope of a slower site.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a **practical solution** for users: Fortunately there's this addon called [LocalCDN](https://www.localcdn.org/) that works exactly as its name suggests: It blocks those requests to [CDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) and loads up those resources locally, hence making loading up jQuery possible even when `ajax.googleapis.com` is blocked.

[image]

Not only is this better for unbreaking Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange on those networks, but also for speed (especially on that poor 4G network that my mobile phone uses with that [addon installed on Firefox Nightly](https://codeberg.org/nobody/LocalCDN/wiki#user-content-13-can-i-use-localcdn-in-firefox-for-android-fenix). A bonus is I get to save some Mbit/s of bandwidth as well and I cannot stress how much my mobile 4G browsing experience has improved since I adopted that addon), but it also protects your privacy from those spooky "free" CDNs.

The addon is free and completely open source (there's even an [auditing script](https://codeberg.org/nobody/LocalCDN/src/branch/main/audit) to verify the integrity of the bundled resources) and I would encourage everyone to give it a try. Anyway, I hope at least someone will find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

China-friendly solution: [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/). They have an ICP license and works reliably in China. Popular resources like jQuery and Bootstrap are available at ease (from NPM) and I just migrated my personal website from Cloudflare's CDNJS to jsDelivr.

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with jsDelivr.