# Replace ajax.googleapis.com

Tags: feature-request, china

Since google services are mostly blocked in China,
StackExchange sites get trouble in showing up because of ajax.googleapis.com.

It is appreciated to replace google refers to maxinum accessiblity.

Think, if you will visit China some day on your vacation or business trip, enhen?

Comment: The problem still exists. Google is able to track users activity on SE sites and nothing was done to stop this.

Comment: Sadly nobody gives attention to this issue. If they do so, great number of Chinese developers can join community and we can learn a lot from mutual collaboration. 

PS: this questionn is not a duplicate of other question. The developers who say it is working correctly, they have misconception. Actually, the file stackoverflow accesses, is stored in browser cache and they think stackoverflow is working correctly. But when they go incognito or use fresh new other browser, website takes time while loading and returns HTML of page after receiving no response from blocked CDN.