# Please redirect jQuery to other cdns for users in China

Tags: feature-request, china

Google's blocked in China, so users here can't assess ajax.google.com. Therefore, users cannot load jQuery, which results in that they can't ask/promote or answer a question/adopt an answer, etc.

Thus, in order to let stackexchange serves people in China as well, I suggest it to redirect users whose IPs are within China to other cdns.(Microsoft/Baidu both provide stable and fast free cdn service for jQuery within China.)

Comment: A support-request about the same: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly

Answer (score 1):

Effort to write

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>')</script>
```

is great.