# How to load Stack Overflow faster?

Tags: discussion, china

When I access to Stack Overflow, I got this sign

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which
>   is blocked or failed to load.

on top of the page because of my lovely country (Google cannot be accessed)... Meanwhile, it took so long time to load the page.
How could I limit the page or JavaScript response/loading time, like 5s or shorter, on Safari or Chrome?
Or is that possible to stop loading that JavaScript file from Google?

Comment: Might want to ask for that to be changed on [Meta.SE] instead.

Comment: Google is blocked in Denmark?

Comment: Also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258288/use-of-ajax-googleapis-com-not-china-friendly

Comment: @ivarni: Added to the list :-)

Comment: @OptimusCrime No, I am in China now.

Comment: @OptimusCrime if it is not Denmark, then the Great Wall of Europe ...

Comment: In your profile you have entered "Copenhagen, Denmark" as your location. Perhaps it is time to update that information?

Comment: I knew something was rotten...